# Cross compiling using Eclipse C/C++ CDT

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cross-platform, eclipse-cdt

I am using a Windows host machine to cross compile programs on to a Linux RT platform using a GCC cross compiler.

Assume, the C program I write, links to a shared library **libShared.so** as I am using functions defined in that library inside my program.

In the Eclipse editor I am providing the library name (libshared.so), and its path under linker options.
Now when I compile the program, I get compilation errors since **libShared.so** links to multiple other libraries (eg: lib11.so, lib12.so, lib13.so), but I am not explicitly calling any functions from these libraries.

My question is, **Why should the compiler generate errors, when I don't explicitly use functions defined in those libraries ?**

However when I specify the name and path of the libraries liked by **libShared.so**, the compilation passes.

Comment: _You_ might not be using those functions but the library you are linking to _does_. If you take them away how do you expect the library to work?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Agreed.  On the other hand, those should be *runtime* dependencies, not compile-time.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you got it right. I don't understand why there is compile time dependency on the libraries referred by the library to which I link across. I expect only run time dependency to the libraries referred by the library to which I link across.
-CaptainObvlious : Could you please let me understand why is this behavior.